# Check if more than one value is in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to check if the numbers 7, 86 and 99 exist in a array called `$category`.

So far I have this, but I don't want to use three lines to do it:

```
if (in_array("7", $category)) {  //do something  }
```

Comment: you only want to do something if all of them exist? `&&` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$search = array("7", "86", "99");
```

If the ids are the keys of the `$category` variable:

```
if (count(array_intersect($search, array_keys($category))) == count($search)) {
  // all found
}
if (count(array_intersect($search, array_keys($category))) > 0) {
  // some found
}
```

If the ids are the values of the `$category` variable:

```
if (count(array_intersect($search, $category)) == count($search)) {
  // all found
}
if (count(array_intersect($search, $category)) > 0) {
  // some found
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) compares arrays m,n and returns any elements of m not in n.

```
count( array_diff( array(7,86,99), $category ) )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (in_array("7", $category) + in_array("86", $category) + in_array("99", $category) >= 2)
   echo "at least two is exist in the array";
```

Update: use `>= 1` or `||`

Comment: `in_array` returns bool, not integer.

Comment: Yes. Please remove the downvote, as boolean are *converted* to integers for the addition operator.

Comment: `true` = 1, `false` = 0. This might not be a pretty way of doing it, but it gets the job done.

Comment: I thought it is a very elegant way of doing it.

Comment: Good point, my mistake. Still, this is a weird way to solve the problem.

Comment: it works great the only problem is I might have to do another check but with like 20 numbers which will get messy